# How can I drag a imagebutton in android

Tags: android, imagebutton, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I'm using `ImageButton`'s in my application. By using `onTouch` event and `onTouchListener` I'm responding to the touch events. 
Once the touch event was completed I'm just displaying the `ImageButton` at target location.
Instead I wanted it to look like dragging of `ImageButton`. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

[This blog](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/moving-views-part-3/#comment-83) has two very nice examples of how you can use touch events to move any kind of view around the screen.

Comment: Thanks, trying to analyze the code. 
If there is a way to assign the values of `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` to the view, then that will make my code much smaller in number lines. Is there any view which supports the above behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. You wrote "Once the touch event was completed [...]" - does that mean you've got it to work in one situation but not others? Are you considering that the touch event is completed when the action of the MotionEvent is  `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`? If you've got that part working, then why not just re-use that same code for the action `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`?

Comment: I'm using `MotionEvent.Action_UP` in my code.  
I have `ImageButton`'s in table layout in layout xml file. One of the `ImageButton`'s is always invisible. When the right `ImageButton` was touched and dragged into the empty cell, I'm making the target `ImageButton` as visible and the one I just dragged as invisible.  
I'm trying to implement the Fifteen puzzle(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifteen_puzzle) game.

Answer (score 0):

Define a own view wich is extending imagebutton, define a drawable for "active" state and set (or reset) the drawable onclick